# Is it true that an uniformizing element of a discrete valuation ring $R$ is either zero or prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be a DVR. This means that it is a PID with a unique maximal ideal. Let us denote $m$ to be the maximal ideal. Then there is a unique irreducible element $\pi$ up to multiplication my a unit such that $m=(\pi)$.

I know that in a PID all maximal ideals are either $(0)$ or $(p)$ where $p\in R$ is prime. Does this denn immediately mean that $\pi$ needs to be zero or prime?

I think this should be true since every PID is a UFD and in a UFD every irreducible element is prime so $\pi$ should be prime or am I wrong?

Thanks for your help.

**Remark** PID=principal ideal domain, UFD=unique factorization domain, DVR=discrete valuation ring

Comment: Yes, $\pi$ is either $0$ or prime. It is $0$ iff $R$ is a field.

Comment: @DouglasMolin perfect thanks!